# Showing $\vert \mathrm{det}(A) \vert \le \prod_{j=1}^n \Vert a_j \Vert_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

### Problem

> Show $\vert \mathrm{det}(A) \vert \le \prod_{j=1}^n \Vert a_j \Vert_2$, where $a_j$ denotes the $j$th column of $A$, which is $n \times n$ matrix.

---

### Try

When $A$ is singular, the result is trivial.

Otherwise, let us consider the matrix $U$, whose $j$th column, $u_j$ has unit length, i.e. $\Vert u_j \Vert_2 = 1, \forall j$. Then

$$
\det(U) \le 1
$$

where equality holds iff $u_j$'s are orthogonal.

I think I need to show

$$
\mathrm{det}(A) = \left( \prod_{j=1}^n \Vert a_j \Vert_2 \right) \det(U) \ \ \ (\ast)
$$

because if it is true then

$$
\left( \prod_{j=1}^n \Vert a_j \Vert_2 \right) \det(U) \le  \prod_{j=1}^n \Vert a_j \Vert_2
$$

But I'm stuck at showing the above $(\ast)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if there's an issue with the post that I have linked, or if there is a detail that you would like clarified.